# how to create a table with side column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Table with side column]

This is a table I need to create. I all most know nothing about frontend, I work with google and ctrl-c, ctrl-v.

I want to create a table like this, the value of the type, key, and value will be filled in backend.

Is there anyone could tell me how to create a table like this, please give me some hints or related resources, thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a coding service. You'll need to attempt this first.

Comment: Thank you, I am not asking for code. I just need some hints, and I will complete this by myself, I know how to programming, just don't know HTML things.

Comment: Ok, but still StackOverflow is [not the place to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) this type of question.

Comment: When working with other elements than tables. You can try searching for css grid. Makes creating any layout really simple.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use colspan and rowpsan on the element you want to set as aside colum.

https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/

Comment: Thank you so much. your suggestion is helpful.